# returned ajax query data undefined

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

Hello I am attempting to create an ajax query but when my results are returned I get **Undefined** as a response. Except for the object called "hello" which returns back as "h" even though it is set to "hello".  I have a feeling it has something to do with the way ajax is sending the data but i'm lost as to what may be the issue.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**here is the ajax**

```
function doSearch() {

    var emailSearchText = $('#email').val();
    var keyCardSearchText = $('#keyCard').val();
    var userNameSearchText = $('#userName').val();
    var pinSearchText = $('#pin').val();
    var passwordSearchText = $('#password').val();


    $.ajax({
        url: 'process.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
        "hello": "hello", 
        "emailtext": "emailSearchText", 
        "keycardtext": "keyCardSearchText", 
        "usernametext": "userNameSearchText",     
        "pinText": "pinSearchText", 
        "passwordtext": "passwordSearchText" 
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data.msg);
            var mydata = data.data_db;
            alert(mydata[0]);
        }
    });
}
```

**Then here is the php**

```
include_once('connection.php');

if(isset($_POST['hello'])) {

        $hello = $_POST['hello'];
        $emailSearchText = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['emailSearchText']);
        $keyCardSearchText = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['keyCardSearchText']);
        $userNameSearchText = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userNameSearchText']);
        $pinSearchText = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pinSearchText']);
        $passwordSearchText = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['passwordSearchText']);


        $query = "SELECT * FROM Students WHERE (`User name`='$userNameSearchText' OR `Email`='$emailSearchText' OR `Key Card`='$keyCardSearchText')AND(`Password`='$passwordSearchText'OR `Pin`='$pinSearchText')";
        $students = mysql_query($query);
        $count = (int) mysql_num_rows($students);
        $data =  array();

        while($student = mysql_fetch_assoc($students)) {
            $data[0] = $student['First Name'];
            $data[1] = $student['Last Name'];
            $data[2] = $student['Date of last class'];
            $data[3] = $student['Time of last class'];
            $data[4] = $student['Teacher of last class'];
            $data[5] = $student['Membership Type'];
            $data[6] = $student['Membership Expiration Date'];
            $data[7] = $student['Free Vouchers'];
            $data[8] = $student['Classes Attended'];
            $data[9] = $student['Classes From Pack Remaining'];
            $data[10] = $student['5 Class Packs Purchased'];
            $data[11] = $student['10 Class Packs Purchased'];
            $data[12] = $student['Basic Memberships Purchased'];
            $data[13] = $student['Unlimited Memberships Purchased'];
            $data[14] = $student['Groupon Purchased'];  
        };

        echo json_encode(array("data_db"=>$data, "msg" => "Ajax connected. The students table consist ".$count." rows data", "success" => true));                   


};
```

Comment: data should be a string with the json; eval() it in your js. (=> is a wrong idea)

Comment: @bwoebi No it shouldn't.  With `dataType: "json"` jquery handles that for you.

Comment: @bwoebi, please put that as an answer so I can downvote it.

Comment: @DerekHenderson I put this as a comment because I was unsure...? (p.s.: someone had now the idea to post the same than I first thought...)

Comment: @James Montagne, that's what I though also but i'm still new to this.  Any suggestions on why it's happening?

Comment: what is the response of `alert(data)`? Better try there console.log(data) and post results.

Comment: hey @SteveBeaty put `exit;` after this `echo json_encode(array("data_db"=>$data, "msg" => "Ajax connected. The students table consist ".$count." rows data", "success" => true));                   
`

Comment: @GrzegorzKaczan the console is not reporting any errors. I would post but that would just be a blank page.   Did you mean alert(data.data_db)?  if so then i'm also getting an undefined.

Comment: @DevalShah I tried that also, still no luck

Comment: No, try just `alert(data)`, no properties of it.

Comment: @GrzegorzKaczan ok i get it now,  I'm getting [object Object] as a response

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your PHP script is likely producing error messages because the $_POST values you are trying to access don't match the key names you are sending in the request. For example: `$_POST['emailSearchText']`, yet you used `emailtext` in the AJAX call.

This is most likely causing jQuery to not be able to parse the response as JSON, hence the Undefined.

Comment: I can't believe that I did that to myself, Thank you

Comment: on a side note I'm just curious on why when I returned the hello portion alone it came back as just the first character "h".

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have to remove the quotes or you will be passing those literals instead of the variables.

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    data: {
    hello: "hello", 
    emailtext: emailSearchText, 
    keycardtext: keyCardSearchText, 
    usernametext: userNameSearchText,     
    pinText: pinSearchText, 
    passwordtext: passwordSearchText 
    },
    ...
});
```

And then, like [ashicus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16701056/1486701) point out, in your PHP file:

```
$emailSearchText = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['emailtext']);
$keyCardSearchText = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['keycardtext']);
$userNameSearchText = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['usernametext']);
$pinSearchText = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pinText']);
$passwordSearchText = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['passwordtext']);
```

Comment: makes sense, though I've since removed the quotes but still no luck

Comment: You can use Firebug to check the requests header and response.

Comment: still getting **Undefined** after the edit, it seems like that should be it though. I really don't get this one.  when I check the header it reads data_db: ""   which is what i expected but now its figuring out why

Comment: Not cool to correct you post after reading better answer by @ashicus.

Comment: You have to change your PHP file. The $_POST keys have the same name as the parameters you use in data{ }.

Comment: I also upvoted the other answer. Just thought it would be more useful to have both corrections in one post.

Answer (score 0):

JS file looks ok, so this few clues to check PHP file.

1. See if there are even POST params there (printr all $_POST in php)
2. Check if your even enters IF. Add an else statement and echo some dummy json.
3. Check what is actually in encoded json that is echoed. Assign it to var then print.